# android.transition:ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have met an exception below:

[image]

I checked the activity stack, the activity stack is empty. I just have no idea what caused this exception, when it happens. Thank You in advance

Comment: You need to post more than an exception if you expect help. Please explain what you're doing when this happens. Your device? Your api level? What steps you do to trigger this? Read this and try again: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is reported by the end users, I never reproduced it. I happened on various devices. My min api level is android 4.3 and target version is 26

Comment: OK, well, your best best is probably going to be to add logging to your app that you can review along with the crash reports to get a better sense of when and where the app is crashing. A stacktrace that's not part of your app is impossible to debug.